# Can someone give me a solid principle for not getting "non object ..." with laravel 5.5?

Tags: laravel-5

Over the time i've been practicing some solutions to avoid non object error in laravel (different versions) , but i wanted to know if there is a solid way to avoid "non object" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [optional helper](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/helpers#method-optional)

```
optional($user->address)->street
```